# How can I edit the default TestNG html report

Tags: report, testng

I don't want to create a new one or a custom listener. Is that possible? Where is the html report created in TestNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SuiteHTMLReporter [[source]](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/SuiteHTMLReporter.java) is the reporter creating the html report.  You can extend and override.  Disable default listeners and add your own.

Comment: I have to extend this class?

Comment: If you could provide me with a small example it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old , but these reports can be edited and custom reports can be made like below. I have explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309879/how-dataprovider-publish-the-test-data-into-html-report/47426325#47426325) how `TestHTMLReporter` can be edited

With your `customReport` You'd have to implement `IReporter` , extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `generateReport` method if you want to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java) . For other reporters you may have to do things a bit  differently but the concept will remain the same. You'd achieve custom 'TestHTMLReporter' like below .

Create a `CustomReport.java` file in your project and copy-paste the whole content of `TestHTMLReporter.java` , change the name of file in `getOutputFile` method  and it would look like below

```
public class CustomReport  extends TestListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }
   ...
   //paste the content of TestHTMLReporter.java here
   ...
   ...
```

Make sure all your imports are in place from `TestHTMLReporter.java`
Now, in this file  change as per your requirement . For ex: if you'd like to add the end time of each of the test then at the correct place in `generateTable` method  add the below snippet

```
// Test class
      String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
       long testMillis = tr.getEndMillis();
        String testMillisString = Long.toString(testMillis);
      if (testClass != null) {
        pw.append("<br>").append("Test class Name: ").append(testClass);

         // this line to add end time in ms
        pw.append("<br>").append("End Time(ms): ").append(testMillisString); 
        // Test name
        String testName = tr.getTestName();
        if (testName != null) {
          pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");

        }
```

Then you'll get like below

[image]

Now, You'll get two reports one with default and the other with your file name.
The only thing now remains is switching off the default reporting listeners, so you get only one report. For that you can follow [this](http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/How-to-disable-a-specific-default-reporter-and-listener-td23194.html) or you may search for solutions. Hope this helps