# How Dataprovider publish the test data into HTML report

Tags: testng, testng-dataprovider

I just googled but didn't get any idea about that how dataprovider publish the test data into default TestNG report. If anybody expert about the internal logic of dataprovider please let me know. It would be appreciate if there is any document to understand this better.

I just created a custom annotation which I want to publish into default testNG HTML report like DataProvider did. I have been tried the below code so far.

The below class will create annotation:

```
     @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
     @Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
     public @interface Greet {
        /**
         * @return - The name of the person to greet.
         */
        String name() default "";
}
```

The below class will get data from user:

```
  public class TestCase1 {
    @Test
    @DataPublish(name="First Test method_1")
    public static void test1() throws Exception {
       try {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
           } 
       catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I would like to print that annotation value in testNG default HTML report.

Comment: what data you want to pass to reporters and what logic are you looking for . Dataprovider is explained [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders). Basically what are you trying to achieve? You can edit the question and explain.

Comment: For what i can see from the provided info , you'd have to use `dataprovider ` to pass data to your classes that extend `TestHTMLReporter.java` or `SuiteHTMLReporter.java` or implements `IReporter` depending on what you want to do

Comment: I noticed that suitehtmlreporter.java has methods which is private and I don't think so it can be extends to child class. Any clue to implement the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dataprovider can provide data to any of the class or methods ,I am sure there are examples for that out there.  You can add your data in the below class.  I have explained the custom reporting part below.

With your `customReport` You'd have to implement `IReporter` , extend `TestListenerAdapter` and override `generateReport` method if you want to implement a custom [`TestHTMLReporter`](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java) . For other reporters you may have to do things a bit  differently but the concept will remain the same. You'd achieve custom 'TestHTMLReporter' like below .

Create a `CustomReport.java` file in your project and copy-paste the whole content of `TestHTMLReporter.java` , change the name of file in `getOutputFile` method  and it would look like below

```
public class CustomReport  extends TestListenerAdapter implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }
   ...
   //paste the content of TestHTMLReporter.java here
   ...
   ...
```

Make sure all your imports are in place from `TestHTMLReporter.java`
Now, in this file  change as per your requirement . For ex: if you'd like to add the end time of each of the test then at the correct place in `generateTable` method  add the below snippet

```
// Test class
      String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
       long testMillis = tr.getEndMillis();
        String testMillisString = Long.toString(testMillis);
      if (testClass != null) {
        pw.append("<br>").append("Test class Name: ").append(testClass);

         // this line to add end time in ms
        pw.append("<br>").append("End Time(ms): ").append(testMillisString); 
        // Test name
        String testName = tr.getTestName();
        if (testName != null) {
          pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");

        }
```

Then you'll get like below

[image]

Now, You'll get two reports one with default and the other with your file name.
The only thing now remains is switching off the default reporting listeners, so you get only one report. For that you can follow [this](http://testng.1065351.n5.nabble.com/How-to-disable-a-specific-default-reporter-and-listener-td23194.html) or you may search for solutions. Hope this helps

Comment: I just copied the code from TestHTMLReporter.java and pasted into my class file and observed error in 256 line in that class file (try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Utils.openWriter(outputDirectory, getOutputFile(testContext)))) {). And it says that openWriter is undefined type of Utils class. Also I have properly imported that class file in my customhtml.java

Comment: Sorry. Its version issue. I have upgraded the testNG in my eclipse ide. Its resolved that issue. Also, I made some changes which is also replicated in default html file. Is there any way to do that same with emailable and index.html report?

Comment: I am not sure right away how to do those. I will have to look into. You can open new question , may be someone will answer or i will  try to answer.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @ArrchanaMohan I think , I have an idea how to do index.html , but I cant explain here, too short of space. So if you open a question, I can answer that.

Comment: Yep. I opened the new ticket for this query. pls find the url below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546020/how-to-override-the-index-html-report-in-testng